# Is the variance of a random variable related to difference of square factorization?

Tags: random-variables, operator-theory, question-verification

Let $X$ be a random variable. The variance ($\sigma_X^2$) of $X$ is calculated by the formula:

$$\sigma_X^2=\Bbb E[X^2]-(\Bbb E[X])^2$$

Is there two operators acting on $X$ that outputs $\sqrt{\Bbb E[X^2]}+\Bbb E[X]$ for the first ($T_1$) and $\sqrt{\Bbb E[X^2]}-\Bbb E[X]$ for the second ($T_2$)? Satisfying the relationship:

$$T_1(X)T_2(X)=\sigma_X^2 $$

And if there is not, but there is some kind of relation between difference of squares and the variance?

Comment: I never thought of variance this way, but yes: it is pretty obvious that you can do that. And now?

Comment: @KurtG. I was thinking of defining the covariance and other statisdistics with respect to this operators, but I didn't get luck. I notice that you can write it as a vector $\vec\sigma_X$ and the inner product should be a Minkowsky inner product, or in another way, a complex number with $j^2=1$ (I always forget how it's called that type of number). If you take the product of $(\vec \sigma_X +\vec \sigma_Y)(\bar\sigma_X + \bar\sigma_Y)=\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y+\text{ some other terms}$, but that other terms don't compute $2\sigma_{X,Y}$ as I would expect.

Comment: The numbers are call split-complex numbers